# I can't find what's causing an error here

Tags: errors

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric, citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[font=it,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{TikZ}
\usepackage{PGF}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\footnoteref[1]{\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\ref{#1}}\@footnotemark}
\makeatother

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment{Eqn}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Spvek}[2][r]{%
  \gdef\@VORNE{1}
  \left(\hskip-\arraycolsep%
     \begin{array}{#1}\vekSp@lten{#2}\end{array}%
  \hskip-\arraycolsep\right)}

\def\vekSp@lten#1{\xvekSp@lten#1;vekL@stLine;}
\def\vekL@stLine{vekL@stLine}
\def\xvekSp@lten#1;{\def\temp{#1}%
  \ifx\temp\vekL@stLine
  \else
    \ifnum\@VORNE=1\gdef\@VORNE{0}
    \else\@arraycr\fi%
    #1%
    \expandafter\xvekSp@lten
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}

\begin{aligned}

\end{aligned}

\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which TeX distribution do you use and in which version? **What is the error you get?** You asked several question without telling which error you get. That is not helpful for people willing helping you ... So add the complete error message to your question you get

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Blank lines inside `equation` environments are not allowed.

```
\begin{equation}

\begin{aligned}

\end{aligned}

\end{equation}
```

If you just rewrite it like this,

```
\begin{equation}    
\begin{aligned} 
...  
\end{aligned}    
\end{equation}
```

the error disappears.

There are also some warnings related to wrong names of packages `TikZ` and `PGF` should be small case and you should add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}` and the `csquotes` package. Warnings will disappear if you do the following. A piece of advice, though, is to load only the necessary packages and only whenever you need them.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric, citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[font=it,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots,csquotes}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
```

Comment: that's still not working for me

Comment: Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable t
ick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} into 
your preamble.
 on input line 46.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd")
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.49 
     
?

Comment: I get that error

Comment: @I.Auguste - Please see my updated answer and if the code still gives errors, append it to the question so that we can test again.